# Refit inheritance misses methods

Tags: refit

We use Refit for our API declarations and want to use Interface inheritance.
A sample is shown here: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#interface-inheritance

```
public interface IPlatformRestClient
{
    HttpClient Client { get; }

    [Get("/version")]
    Task<string> GetVersion();
}

public interface ITestRestClient : IPlatformRestClient
{
    [Get("/test")]
    Task<string> Test();
}
```

I may be blind and do something wrong, but the construct results in the following error message

> 'AutoGeneratedITestRestClient' does not implement interface member 'IPlatformRestClient.GetVersion()' Platform.RestClient.UnitTests

And if I open the stubs:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
[global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
[Preserve]
[global::System.Reflection.Obfuscation(Exclude=true)]
partial class AutoGeneratedITestRestClient : ITestRestClient
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public HttpClient Client { get; protected set; }
    readonly IRequestBuilder requestBuilder;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public AutoGeneratedITestRestClient(HttpClient client, IRequestBuilder requestBuilder)
    {
        Client = client;
        this.requestBuilder = requestBuilder;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    Task<string> ITestRestClient.Test()
    {
        var arguments = new object[] {  };
        var func = requestBuilder.BuildRestResultFuncForMethod("Test", new Type[] {  });
        return (Task<string>)func(Client, arguments);
    }
}
```

So is this feature broken or do I have any error?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Interface inheritance works only if all interfaces are located in one project

Comment: this is an [open Issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/650) for Refit library as interface inheritance works only in case if they are in the same project.

Comment: @NaushadWarsi nice to see you again. You found my GitHub issue :-)

Comment: thanks for this post! I am having a similar problem with inherited interfaces. I really needed this to work, so the quick fix was to declare all methods from the parent interface in the child interface as new. Defeats the purpose of inheritance but I am glad I have found this post and the bug reference so I can keep an eye on that fix.